# Permanent File Location In iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

When deploying to an iOS, the documents path of the previous copy of the app is deleted and a new documents path is created and the files are copied to that new path.

What if you want to place a file that you do not want to get deleted each time you redeploy your app?  Is this possible and if so where is a good location to place this file?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? What's the problem with the sandbox being moved on each update/redeploy?

Comment: Don't you ever have something important like the last time you synced a database that you wish was not deleted???  I said file.  I could have said database.  I cannot believe that there is not a safe place that you can store a file/database that is not deleted every time you redeploy.

Comment: Why do you think files are deleted? The sandbox may be moved but most files are kept. Everything in the Documents folder and most files under Library are kept. OF course if you delete the app then all files or deleted. But updating the app, files are kept.

Comment: The documents directory is most certainly NOT deleted. The Temporary directory will be though...

Comment: Well explain this.  This is the GetDocumentsPath that is used and here are the results of redeployments.  Notice the use of GUIDs.  '/var/mobile/Applications/93449BA6-0144-47AA-989E-57C9AA18C693/Documents/ILPocketDb.db'
'/var/mobile/Applications/7D14F886-F8EE-4206-94B2-C6103B8E5830/Documents/ILPocketDb.db'
'/var/mobile/Applications/CB4FEC66-E8C5-4382-BD8F-18EF4D0188EB/Documents/ILPocketDb.db'

Comment: Every time you redeploy a new path including a GUID is issued.  So forget about the old path.  You can no longer reference it.  Any more suggestions???

Comment: So I guess the question is since you'll believe that the documents folder is still intact, can you set redeployment to the same documents folder?  And if so, how can you find it?

Comment: Every time your app runs, you determine the path to the Documents folder at runtime and then build your path to the db file from there. It's simple and it has been done this way since iOS 2.0. You never store absolute paths. You never assume a specific path to the sandbox.

Comment: Did you read my comments about redeployment???  You have no control over where iOS installs the ipa.  You must backup your talk with examples else your sandbox principle falls apart.

Comment: Instead of getting the absolute path, always use the relative path from Documents. So whatever the GUID of the app, you will able to get your document without any issue.

Comment: @tj I don't think you are listening. It's irrelevant that the path keeps changing. As you have been told several times, don't store absolute paths. You must calculate the path to the Documents folder at runtime EVERY TIME your app runs. It can and will change. There are a million apps in the app store. Any of them that save data easily deal with this. You can too. Do a search on using `NSDocumentDirectory`. You will find countless examples on how to get the path at runtime.

Comment: Again, what I am talking about is "REDEPLOYMENT" and I am listening, but you are not giving me credit.  I have no problem finding the documents path each and every time I run the application.  I just asked a simple question about where is a good place I can put a file/database in that I can find each and every time not dependent upon the GUID crazy redeployment fiasco.  I quit, last comment.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstand of what you mean by redeployment. All of the replies you've received assume you mean that the app is installed and then the app is updated. What do you exactly mean by "redeployment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about when you compile and deploy from Delphi to the device. It uninstalls the previous deployment of the app first before it installs the new deployment. Naturally this deletes everything in the app sandbox.

Normally, in real life this would not be a problem because updating an app to a newer version from the app store leaves alone anything that is in the Documents directory.

This applies to XE5 and older. In XE6 this behavior has been changed. In XE6 the deployment to device leaves the old documents, data and cache directories alone, so the old stuff stays there. And there is an optional switch to do it the old way and delete everything.

So, the solution is to upgrade to XE6. There is no other known way.

Comment: Thank you for putting part of this to rest.  Still trying to figure out if there is another permanent folder that I can place the file/database and access it.